# can i have custom links in so snippets?

Tags: code-snippets, react.rb

Can I load my own custom libraries with Stack Overflow's new snippet editor?  Can I use custom script tags?  I would like to have examples using [inline reactive-ruby](https://github.com/reactive-ruby/inline-reactive-ruby) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow it works!

Here is an example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/reactive-ruby/inline-reactive-ruby/master/inline-reactive-ruby.js"></script>

<div id="timer-target"></div>

<script type="text/ruby">

class Ticker < React::Component::Base

  before_mount do
    state.ticks! 0
    @timer = every(1) {state.ticks! state.ticks+1}
  end

  before_unmount do
    @timer.stop
  end

  def render
    div {"Seconds Elapsed: #{state.ticks}"}
  end

end

Element['#timer-target'].render { Ticker() }
</script>
```